# Images slide show in android

Tags: android, json, image

I want  to show images as slide show in android. That images will come from the server in the json data format. Can you tell me how i can pass that images in the images slider that will display the images. number of images coming from the server in json, it is totally dynamic, a group of images...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Intially you need to do is to take the count of the images coming from the json.As you get all the images you can show it to user using the horizondal pages.It helps to change the image in each swipe like in this [link](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-user-interface-design-horizontal-view-paging/) .Otherwise you can use two frames and can set two animations and show it like an slider.I think this piece of code will help you.

```
if (imagesetflag == true) {
                Right_to_left_in = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
                        R.anim.right_to_left_in);
                Right_to_left_out = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
                        R.anim.right_to_left_out);
                left_to_Right_in = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
                        R.anim.left_to_right_in);
                Left_to_Right_out = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
                        R.anim.left_to_right_out);

                frame1.setImageBitmapReset(decryptedimage, 0, true);
                TVpagenum.setText("Page no:" + Currentpage + "/"
                        + countOfPages);
                frame1.bringToFront();
                frame1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                frame2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                frame1.setAnimation(Right_to_left_in);
                frame2.setAnimation(Right_to_left_out);                                     
                imagesetflag = false;
            } else {
                Right_to_left_in = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
                        R.anim.right_to_left_in);
                Right_to_left_out = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
                        R.anim.right_to_left_out);
                left_to_Right_in = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
                        R.anim.left_to_right_in);
                Left_to_Right_out = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
                        R.anim.left_to_right_out);

                frame2.setImageBitmapReset(decryptedimage, 0, true);
                TVpagenum.setText("Page no:" + Currentpage + "/"
                        + countOfPages);
                frame2.bringToFront();
                frame2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                frame1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                frame2.setAnimation(Right_to_left_in);
                frame1.setAnimation(Right_to_left_out);                 
                imagesetflag = true;
            }
```

Comment: Upvoting and accepting answer Help us both to improve the reputation in stackoverflow.So happy to help you.thank by accepting ang the answer and upvoting.:-)

Answer (score 2):

You should parse the coming Json Data and get the image urls.
With that data you can use a ViewPager and in its adapter you can execute asyncTask to 
display images in ViewPager's item layout.

Or you can use ViewFlipper with animations (like fade-in , fade-out) for your slider.
The logic should be the same